# adding an active state to menu link with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add an active state to my fadetoggle menu.

When the user clicks on one of the menu options, the menu fades in and with it an arrow appears under the active menu item. The menu fades in and out when the user clicks on it, what I cant get right is the active state. I have seen a couple of examples online. I want simple to understand code and I have come up with the following javascript code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.menu-item-recovery a').live('click', function(event) {
        $('.recovery-bg').show();
        $('.recovery-bg').addClass('active');
        return false;
    });
});
```

When the user clicks on any of the links below:

```
<!--Logo & Second Nav-->
<div class="container hidden-phone">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span9 second-nav">
            <div class="menu-wrapper">
                <div class="menu-item-recovery recovery trigger" data-target=".recovery-bg">
                    <a href="#">Recovery</a>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item-forensic trigger" data-target=".forensic-bg">
                    <a href="#">Forensics</a>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item-erasure trigger" data-target=".erasure-bg">
                    <a href="#">Erasure</a>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item-training trigger" data-target=".training-bg">
                    <a href="#">Training</a>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item-products trigger" data-target=".product-bg">
                    <a href="#">Products</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!--/Logo & Second Nav-->
```

The following menu fades in and an active state needs to be added to it:

```
<!--Expanding Recovery Menu-->
<div class="recovery-bg arrow_box_recovery toggle hidden-phone">
    <div class="container expand">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="menu-item menu-item-1 menu-first-rec">
                    <a href="http://dev.disklabs.com/html/data-recovery.html">
                    <p>Data <br/> Recovery</p></a>
                </div>  
                <div class="menu-item menu-item-2">
                    <a href="">
                    <p>Raid <br/> Recovery</p></a>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item menu-item-3">
                    <a href="">
                    <p>Forensic <br/> Data Recovery</p></a>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-item menu-item-4">
                    <a href="">
                    <p>Tape <br/> Recovery</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/Expanding Recovery Menu-->
```

css for the active state, not sure where I need to put it:

```
.active {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  background: url(../img/menu-arrow-recovery.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: The active state should only appear when the menu fades in and should disappear when the menu fades out.

Comment: I was looking at your website and I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Would you mind publishing a screenshot of what you want the menu to look like when open?

Comment: When you click on a menu item (like recovery, forensic & training) the toggle menu fades in and at the top of that toggle menu should be an arrow pointing towards which ever menu item was clicked whether it was recovery or forensics. Im sorry I don't have a screenshot.

Comment: Tried adding a screenshot but was unable to, stackoverflow isnt allowing my profile to add one yet. sorry.

Comment: Here's a rudimentary fiddle that toggles a hidden menu off and on when clicking on the visible menu. Once you see the "invisible" menu, what do you want to do?http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/6cWW8/

Comment: Thanks @TimSPQR I have edited your fiddle with my code which I have managed to implement and get working for my site. I needed the arrow to show up on the background as it toggles the menu. here is the link to my fiddle [link]http://jsfiddle.net/F4SJ8/ I have added a quick overview of my code. I used cssarrowplease with background images and managed to get it working the way i wanted. I tried to add my answer but wasnt able to because you cant answer your own question within 8 hours. But it works which is the main thing. (:

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the cssarrowplease code I found through the stackoverflow forums. I have added a link to it [cssarrowplease](http://cssarrowplease.com/) Its a great tool and I customised it a little because the site is responsive I changed the css so that I could add a different active arrow for every dropdown arrow. Here is the code I ended up with to achieve this.

```
/*------------------------------------
/ Recovery Navigation Arrow
/-----------------------------------*/
.arrow_box_recovery {
  position: relative;
  background: #05f397;
  /*border: 4px solid $recovery;*/
}

.arrow_box_recovery:after {
  content: url("http://dev.disklabs.com/html/assets/img/menu-arrow-recovery.png") no-repeat;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -13%;
  margin-left: -80px;
  bottom: 100%;
  border: solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box_recovery:after {
  border-color: rgba(5, 243, 151, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #05f397;
}

.arrow_box_recovery:before {
  border-color: rgba(5, 243, 151, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #05f397;
}
```

Here is a link to my fiddle gives an example of what I wanted to achieve.
[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F4SJ8/)

Hopefully it might help someone else looking to achieve the same thing.